# How to read and write Identified Data Serializable in Hazelcast

Tags: hazelcast, hazelcast-jet

i have a problem and the documentations and github examples doesn't provide a clear example about how to do it....

i have this class

```
public class KeySerializable implements IdentifiedDataSerializable{



private String claveReq;
private int id_interno_pe;
private String cod_nrbe_en;
private int num_sec_ac;
public KeySerializable(String claveReq, int id_interno_pe, String cod_nrbe_en, int num_sec_ac) {
    this.claveReq = claveReq;
    this.id_interno_pe = id_interno_pe;
    this.cod_nrbe_en = cod_nrbe_en;
    this.num_sec_ac = num_sec_ac;
}
public KeySerializable() {
}
public void writeData(ObjectDataOutput out) throws IOException {
    out.writeString(claveReq);
    out.writeInt(id_interno_pe);
    out.writeString(cod_nrbe_en);
    out.writeInt(num_sec_ac);
    
}
public void readData(ObjectDataInput in) throws IOException {
    this.claveReq = in.readString();
    this.id_interno_pe = in.readInt();
    this.cod_nrbe_en = in.readString();
    this.num_sec_ac = in.readInt();
    
}
public int getFactoryId() {
    return KeySerializableFactory.FACTORY_ID;
}
public int getClassId() {
    return KeySerializableFactory.KEY_SERIALIZABLE_TYPE;
}
@Override
public String toString() {
    return "KeySerializable [claveReq=" + claveReq + ", id_interno_pe=" + id_interno_pe + ", cod_nrbe_en="
            + cod_nrbe_en + ", num_sec_ac=" + num_sec_ac + "]";
}
```

}

and this class

```
public class ResponseSerializablePlus implements IdentifiedDataSerializable{




private int id_interno_pe;
private String cod_nrbe_en;
private int num_sec_ac;
private int statusCode;
private HashMap<String,List<String>> headers;
private byte[] content;
public ResponseSerializablePlus(int id_interno_pe, String cod_nrbe_en, int num_sec_ac, int statusCode,
        HashMap<String, List<String>> headers, byte[] content) {
    this.id_interno_pe = id_interno_pe;
    this.cod_nrbe_en = cod_nrbe_en;
    this.num_sec_ac = num_sec_ac;
    this.statusCode = statusCode;
    this.headers = headers;
    this.content = content;
}
public ResponseSerializablePlus() {
}
public void writeData(ObjectDataOutput out) throws IOException {
    out.writeInt(id_interno_pe);
    out.writeString(cod_nrbe_en);
    out.writeInt(num_sec_ac);
    out.write(statusCode);
    out.writeObject(headers);
    out.writeByteArray(content);
    
}
public void readData(ObjectDataInput in) throws IOException {
    this.id_interno_pe = in.readInt();
    this.cod_nrbe_en = in.readString();
    this.num_sec_ac = in.readInt();
    this.statusCode = in.readInt();
    this.headers = in.readObject();
    this.content = in.readByteArray();
    
}
public int getFactoryId() {
    return ResponseSerializablePlusFactory.FACTORY_ID;
}
public int getClassId() {
    return ResponseSerializablePlusFactory.RESPONSE_SERIALIZABLE_PLUS_CLASS;
}
@Override
public String toString() {
    return "ResponseSerializablePlus [id_interno_pe=" + id_interno_pe + ", cod_nrbe_en=" + cod_nrbe_en
            + ", num_sec_ac=" + num_sec_ac + ", statusCode=" + statusCode + ", headers=" + headers + ", content="
            + Arrays.toString(content) + "]";
}
```

and this other class

```
public class ResponseSerializable implements IdentifiedDataSerializable{



private int statusCode;
private HashMap<String,List<String>> headers;
private byte[] content;
public ResponseSerializable(int statusCode, HashMap<String, List<String>> headers, byte[] content) {
    this.statusCode = statusCode;
    this.headers = headers;
    this.content = content;
}
public ResponseSerializable() {
}

public void writeData(ObjectDataOutput out) throws IOException {
    out.write(statusCode);
    out.writeObject(headers);
    out.writeByteArray(content);
    
}

public void readData(ObjectDataInput in) throws IOException {
    this.statusCode = in.readInt();
    this.headers = in.readObject();
    this.content = in.readByteArray();
    
}
public int getFactoryId() {
    
    return ResponseSerializableFactory.FACTORY_ID;
}
public int getClassId() {
    return ResponseSerializableFactory.RESPONSE_TYPE;
}
@Override
public String toString() {
    return "ResponseSerializable [statusCode=" + statusCode + ", headers=" + headers + ", content="
            + Arrays.toString(content) + "]";
}
```

}

and the factory it's always the same but with different classes

```
public class KeySerializableFactory implements DataSerializableFactory{

public static final int FACTORY_ID = 1;

public static final int KEY_SERIALIZABLE_TYPE = 1;

public IdentifiedDataSerializable create(int typeId) {
    if ( typeId == KEY_SERIALIZABLE_TYPE ) {
        return new KeySerializable();
    } else {
        return null;
    }
}
```

}

and im always having this bunch errors

[image]

the documentation and the github examples from hazelcast doesn't provide a good example about how to use the getters and setters and i don't understand what to do here to write or read an object

any hint? can you help me?

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't be calling `readData` or `writeData` yourself. These methods are called by Hazelcast internally when the data is about to be serialized/deserialized.

On your side, you should only register the data serializable factories you have created to the Hazelcast.

Then, upon receiving an instance of a class that implements `IdentifiedDataSerializable` and has a factory registered for it, Hazelcast will call the methods I mentioned above in appropriate places and return you the object read.

From the code sample you shared, you need to drop the line starting with `newResponse.writeData(...`, and everything should be working, assuming you did the factory registration.

Also, please fix your `ResponseSerializablePlus` and `ResponseSerializable` classes: You need to use `writeInt` method to write the `statusCode` field. The `readData` and `writeData` methods should be consistent with each other.

Comment: that's why im not understanding everything at all, i'm trying to fill an object and that's why i need to set a value, ¿How would you do it? thank you.

Comment: You can call the setters and after you constructed the object locally, when you do `map.put(key, value)`, Hazelcast will call the `writeData` internally to serialize your object. As a user, you do not perform any action other than constructing your object and calling `map.put` etc.